# Tensorflow: SavedModelBuilder, How to save model with best validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tflearn

I have gone through tensorflow documentation but couldn't find the way of saving model with best validation accuracy, using SavedModelBuilder class. 
I am using tflearn for model building and below is the work around i have tried but it is taking lot of time, where i am running fit method for each epoch separately and saving model

```
for i in range(epoch):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=1, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True, batch_size=8)
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('/tmp/serving/model/' + str(i))
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(model.session,
                                     ['TRAINING'],
                                     signature_def_map={
                                         'predict': prediction_sig
                                     })
    builder.save()
```

Please suggest if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It can be achieved through tflearn callbacks.
Thanks.

```
class SaveModelCallback(tflearn.callbacks.Callback):
def __init__(self, accuracy_threshold):
    self.accuracy_threshold = accuracy_threshold
    self.accuracy = []
    self.max_accuracy = -1

def on_epoch_end(self, training_state):
    self.accuracy.append(training_state.global_acc)
    if training_state.val_acc > self.accuracy_threshold and training_state.val_acc > self.max_accuracy:
        self.max_accuracy = training_state.val_acc
        epoch = training_state.epoch
        self.save_model(epoch)

def save_model(self, epoch):
    print('saved epoch ' + str(epoch))
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('/tmp/serving/model/' + str(epoch))
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(model.session,
                                         [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map={
                                             'predict': prediction_sig,
                                             tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
                                                 classification_signature,
                                         })
    builder.save()

callback = SaveModelCallback(accuracy_threshold=0.8)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=200, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True, batch_size=8,
          callbacks=callback)
```

Comment: Do you know how tflearn did it? Any related code? I need this in my code without tflearn.

Comment: @WeiLiu, i have edited the answer, let me know if it works for you